# execute click event over selected text in firefox

Tags: firefox

Sometimes I search for a link, like download or a specific language in wikipedia, and click it right after the web browser found it. Moving my cursor over it is excessive. Also, often I must search it manually the second time, because it's not even centered or barely highlighted.

I would like it to be clicked with a quick keyboard press. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the arrow keys to navigate around the page, and the TAB key to focus on the next anchor.